# USB-trigger not firing, or service not run, on subsequent connects

Tags: linux, systemd, usb

**The problem:**

I have a tablet w. stylus. I'd like the tablet to undergo some configuration whenever I connect it via USB. I'm almost there, my config-script is registered with systemctl as a *oneshot* service and that service is triggered the first time I connect the tablet.  However the service is not triggered on subsequent connects: in other words, if I disconnect the tablet and reconnect it, the trigger is not fired. I have to do a `systemctl --user daemon-reload` before the trigger becomes active again. What am I missing?

**System:** OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 Kernel: 5.4.0-52-lowlatency

**Here is my trigger:**

filename: `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-wacom.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", 
ATTR{idVendor}=="256c", 
ATTR{idProduct}=="006d", 
MODE="0666", 
TAG+="systemd", 
ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="tablet-conf.service"
```

*(there are no linebreaks in the actual file, I just put them in for easier reading)*

**Here is my service-definition:**

filename: `~/.config/systemd/user/tablet-conf.service`

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/huion-inspiroy-950d-connect.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=xsession.target
```

**Here's my configuration-script**:

Filename: `~/bin/system/devices/huion-inspiroy-950d-connect.sh`

Called via a symlink `/usr/local/bin/huion-inspiroy-950d-connect.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /home/esm/bin/system/devices/a-connected-waiting
sleep 2
touch /home/esm/bin/system/devices/a-connected-waited
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d stylus" MapToOutput HEAD-0 2>> /home/esm/bin/system/devices/a-configured
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d stylus" rotate HALF 2>> /home/esm/bin/system/devices/a-configured
```

*(as you can see, I create some empty files and log som info during the configuration. All this is of course not necessary, but I needed it, when I was figuring out how to get the trigger working. I'll remove it, once I've figured out how to get the whole thing to behave)*

**So the question is ...**

How can I achieve that the trigger is fired on every tablet-connection, and not just the first?

Comment: I dont think you need the `WantedBy=xsession.target`? What does `systemctl --user status tablet-conf` say after each plug-in?

Comment: I've deleted the Wantedby line and you're right. I don't need it.


Message after first connect and second connect is the same, only the "inactive since" time is updated

`Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-11-05 21:30:38 CET; 39s ago`

`Main PID: 7994 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Comment: I tried something similar for an ftdi serial usb device and it seemed ok on a 2nd plug in. Does `udevadm monitor -t=systemd` show the tablet being added each time?

Comment: `udevadm monitor -t=systemd` shows nothing at all 

`udevadm monitor` gives a lot of `devices` paths. Seemingly no difference between the outputs from first and subsequent connects

Comment: I should perhaps add that the device connects fully on subsequent connects, and can even be configured by the config-script, it's just the trigger that is not fired.

Comment: You should really be seeing it in the output with `-t=systemd`. Try renaming `10-wacom.rules` to `99-mywacom.rules` and `sudo udevadm control --reload`. Perhaps a later rule is breaking things.

Comment: renaming to 99-wacom.rules didn't make any noticeable difference. `-t=systemd`still deadquiet. Am I monitoring the right thing? There seems to be two "modes" of systemd - the systemwide and a usermode (hence the `--user` in `systemctl --user daemon-reload`)